# AND/OR nested queries with different paths in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have somewhat deeply nested objects in elastic search. I'm trying to find an effective way of ANDing/ORing them using bool queries.

Below is my mapping

```
sample:
   type:nested
   properties:
    vendor_detections: 
        type: "nested"
        properties:
            vendor_name: 
                type: string
            signature:
                type:nested
                properties:
                    name:
                        type:string
```

The query which I am trying is give me all samples for whom the detection by a vendor say "microsoft" contains the string "Win32". Below is the query I tried

```
GET /my_index/sample/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "vendor_detections",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                    "vendor_detections.vendor_name": "microsoft"
               }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "vendor_detections.signature",
            "query": {
              "wildcard": {
                    "vendor_detections.signature.name": "Win32*"
               }
            }
          }
        },


      ]
    }
  }
}
```

A "sample" containing the document "vendor_detections"

```
{
  "md5sum": ""
  "vendor_detections": [{
      "vendor_name": "symantec",
      "service_name": "spw",
      "signature": {
          "name": "W32.Wapomi!inf",
          "threat": {
              "vulnerabilities": [],
              "threat_category": {
                  "name": "Unknown"
              },
              "targets": []
          }
      }
  }, {
      "vendor_name": "kaspersky",
      "service_name": "spw",
      "signature": {
          "name": "Virus.Win32.Qvod.f",
          "threat": {
              "vulnerabilities": [],
              "threat_category": {
                  "name": "Unknown"
              },
              "targets": []
          }
      }
  }, {
      "vendor_name": "bitdefender",
      "service_name": "spw",
      "signature": {
          "name": "Win32.Viking.AX",
          "threat": {
              "vulnerabilities": [],
              "threat_category": {
                  "name": "Unknown"
              },
              "targets": []
          }
      }
  }]
}
```

However, this is returning me all samples in which signatures of either of the 4 vendors I use in my application contain the string "Win32". How do I resolve this?

Comment: You have `vendor_detections` (plural)  in your mapping, but `vendor_detection` (singular)  in your query... typo? Also what is the name of the mapping type exactly: `sample` (as in your mapping) or `example` (as in your query)? Those details matter

Comment: @Val Sorry for the typos. Corrected, please see.

Comment: Also note that the `match` query doesn't support wildcards `*`, you need to use the `wildcard` query for that or the `query_string` query

Comment: It still does not work with this change too in its current form.

Comment: I was just pointing out obvious mistakes/typos... Can you also share a sample document please?

Comment: @Val Updated, please check

Comment: Why is signature also a `nested` object since you only have a single one?

Comment: Can we chat in the forum? I am somewhat getting the point now. Maybe my mappings are all wrong.

Comment: Can you put this as an answer @Val, I will upvote and green-check it. I need to recheck my mappings it seems. This worked. Got confused between object and nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information in your question, i.e. the mapping and the sample document, there's no reason to declare `signature` as a nested object since you only have a single one per nested `vendor_detections` object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i havent checked but it should work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "sample.vendor_detections",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "sample.vendor_detections.vendor_name": "microsoft"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "sample.vendor_detections.signature.name": "win32*"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help, however it is not working with this, had already tried it out.